# Matching keys in different lists of dicts

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a `csv.DictReader` instance of dicts and a list of dicts.

instance:

```
{'Salary': '3000', 'Name': 'James Jones', 'GameInfo': 'Den@Cle 07:30PM ET', 
 'AvgPointsPerGame': '4.883', 'teamAbbrev': 'Cle', 'Position': 'SG'}
{'Salary': '3000', 'Name': 'Justin Anderson', 'GameInfo': 'Orl@Dal 09:00PM ET',
 'AvgPointsPerGame': '13.161', 'teamAbbrev': 'Dal', 'Position': 'SF'}
```

list:

```
[

    {'playername': 'Justin Anderson', 'points': '6.94'},

    {'playername': 'DeAndre Liggins', 'points': '11.4'},

]
```

I cannot figure out how to iterate over these lists of dictionaries, match the Name and playername keys, then spit the `['Name']` from one dict and the `['points']` from the matching dict. In the example above I would match Justin Anderson from the two sets of dicts then print out Justin Anderson, 6.94

The core of the app takes 2 CSV's and makes them lists of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really efficient this way but it wouldn't require any preprocessing:

```
# Instead of your CSVReader:
dicts = [{'Salary': '3000', 'Name': 'James Jones', 'GameInfo': 'Den@Cle 07:30PM ET', 'AvgPointsPerGame': '4.883', 'teamAbbrev': 'Cle', 'Position': 'SG'},
         {'Salary': '3000', 'Name': 'Justin Anderson', 'GameInfo': 'Orl@Dal 09:00PM ET', 'AvgPointsPerGame': '13.161', 'teamAbbrev': 'Dal', 'Position': 'SF'}]

list_of_dicts = [
    {'playername': 'Justin Anderson', 'points': '6.94'},
    {'playername': 'DeAndre Liggins', 'points': '11.4'},
]

# For each dictionary in the CSVReader
for dct in dicts:
    # For each dictionary in your list of dictionaries
    for subdict in list_of_dicts:
        # Check if the name and playername matches
        if dct['Name'] == subdict['playername']:
            # I just print out the results, you need to do your logic here
            print(dct['Name'])
            print(dct)
            print('matching')
            print(subdict)
```

and this prints:

```
Justin Anderson
{'Salary': '3000', 'Name': 'Justin Anderson', 'GameInfo': 'Orl@Dal 09:00PM ET', 'AvgPointsPerGame': '13.161', 'Position': 'SF', 'teamAbbrev': 'Dal'}
matching
{'playername': 'Justin Anderson', 'points': '6.94'}
```

If you want it faster than you should preprocess your list of dictionaries so that you can simply lookup the `playername`:

```
>>> dict_of_dicts = {dct['playername']: dct for dct in list_of_dicts}
>>> dict_of_dicts
{'DeAndre Liggins': {'playername': 'DeAndre Liggins', 'points': '11.4'},
 'Justin Anderson': {'playername': 'Justin Anderson', 'points': '6.94'}}
```

Then the loop simplifies to:

```
for dct in dicts:
    if dct['Name'] in dict_of_dicts:
        print(dct['Name'])
        print(dct)
        print('matching')
        print(dict_of_dicts[dct['Name']])
```

giving the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How could I modify this to show Name,AvgPointsPerGame,Points? I cant seem to wrap my head around how exactly "dict_of_dicts = {dct['playername']: dct for dct in list_of_dicts}" works, i need to study up on the syntax. But it is working as you described.

Comment: you could do `print(dct['Name'], dct['AvgPointsPerGame'], dict_of_dicts[dct['Name']]['Points'])`. The `{x:y for ... in ....}` is a dictionary comprehension: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/196/comprehensions/738/dictionary-comprehensions#t=201702121809034331221

Comment: This lead me to the solution very nicely. Thank you MSeifert.